# CordovaApp-debug.apk - rm failed for -f, No such file or directory

Tags: cordova, adb, logcat

I have just started to create mobile apps using Cordova with the framework Ionic, and everything works fine, except this:

```
adb install -r platforms/android/ant-build/CordovaApp-debug.apk
```

. I get the following:

```
3086 KB/s (3489699 bytes in 1.104s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/CordovaApp-debug.apk
Success
rm failed for -f, No such file or directory
```

And I guess that's why I have problems, when I'm using adb logcat.

It's worth mentioning that I have set "everything" up (android, java, git, ant and nodejs) in my environment variables, and I can build my applications and run them on my Samsung Galaxy S3.

Regards,

Comment: Getting the same "Success\n rm failed" here with using Android Studio, but doing a manual install from a terminal to a Samsung Galaxy Note 2. The app installs and runs without a problem, just a little weird on the message. I have no issue with `logcat` from a terminal however.

Comment: Neither have I problems installing and running the apps, it's just that message. When I'm using Eclipse, then I have no issues with logcat.

Answer (score 2):

I set the environment variable "**ADB_TRACE=1**" to see what's happening

> environmental variables:
>    ADB_TRACE                    - Print
>   debug information. A comma separated list of the following values
>                                    1 or all, adb, sockets, packets, rwx, usb, sync, sysdeps, transport, jdwp

In my case, "adb" is trying to delete the apk file from **/data/local/tmp/**

> Line 9966: system/core/adb/adb_client.c::adb_connect():adb_connect:
>   service shell:**rm -f /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk**

So, It seems that "adb" doesn't have the rights to delete the file.

Comment: Weird!  While this isn't really a *problem*, it's quite off-putting.  Yeah, I'm seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Well it is a problem when you install a bunch of different APKs and a copy of each is left in `/data/local/tmp` ... eventually your `/data` partition fills up.  The solution to run `adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/\*` periodically.  Incidentally, I don't think this has anything to do with permissions, I just think the copy of `rm` on some versions of Android doesn't support the `-f` flag which causes the command to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as suggested in a comment, is that the bundled rm does not always support the -f option. To check that this is indeed the case, from an adb shell prompt you can either try the the rm command with and then without -f: the former will fail, or try just "rm": it will probably echo "rm [-rR] target" whereas it would echo "rm [-frR] etc" or some such if it supported the -f option.

However at least on my device this is not benign: the app is not installed!